# How to sample from a Kendalls distribution function for a given copula?

Tags: r

I’m creating a sample vector v=(*v*<sub>1</sub>, ..., *v*<sub>*m*</sub>) from a Gauss copula with a given correlation matrix *CM* and with this I want to create some new variables *z*<sub>*i*</sub>=*K*<sub>*i*</sub><sup>-1</sup>(*v*<sub>*i*</sub>) where *K*<sub>*i*</sub> is the Kendalls distribution function of a Gumbel copula with parameter *CorPar*.

In the “working” part I’m creating a correlation matrix and then I create my random vector *v*.

```
library(QRM)
library(copula)
library(matrixcalc)
library(Matrix) 

CM <- matrix(runif(25),5,5)
CM_PSD <- nearPD(CM, corr=TRUE)$mat
v <- rcopula.gauss(1,as.matrix(CM_PSD))
CorPar <- 1.54
```

Now I want to get my *z* but I fail in running the R-code. As far as I learned from my research this should work somehow with the function *qK* out of the copula-Package.
http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/copula/html/K.html

```
qK(u, cop, d, n.MC=0, method=c("default", "simple", "sort", "discrete", "monoH.FC"), u.grid, ...)
```

`u` is the evaluation point so my `v_i` and since my copula is a 2-dimensional Gumbel copula I’m guessing `d` should be set to `2`.

But I’m constantly failing on the *cop* part and the logic behind an `acopula`.

Can you please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After quite a few more tries and time I finally solved the question by myself.
I don't know for sure why it is working but it is since I can validate my results with a different program. :)

```
 cop_z <- onacopulaL("Gumbel", list(CorPar,1:2))
 z <- qK(v,cop_z@copula, 2)
```